# How to merge a Excel range Interop C#

Tags: c#

How to merge a rang Excel in C# Interop?
I want to merge all from A1 to C3.
I do

```
Rang rang = Cells[1,3] as Rang;
```

But cant work.

```
    A    B    C
1|----|----|----|
2|----|----|----|
3|----|----|----|
 |----|----|----|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourWorksheet.Range[yourWorksheet.Cells[rowBegin,colBegin], yourWorksheet.Cells[yourWorksheet.rowEnd, colEnd]].Merge();
```

Row and Col start at `1`.